# setting a display scale of second monitor large than primary monitor

Tags: 20.04, screen, display-resolution, settings

Display settings seems to keep the same display scale for both primary and secondary monitor displays even when you change one.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to *Settings > Display > Select specific monitor* and set scale.